# Debugging a simple game of guessing number by class 11

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making a game to guess the number by the user. But I am facing a problem while restarting the game. Can you help me do so?

```py
import random

game = True
status = True

while game == True:
    secret_number = random.randint(1,100)

    while status == True:
        guess_number = int(input("Guess a number. "))

        if guess_number == secret_number:
            print("You won the game!!")
            status = False
            another_game = input("Do you want to play once again? (y/n)")

            if another_game == 'y':
                print("OK")
                break

            elif another_game == 'n':
                print("Thankyou for Playing")
                game == False

        elif guess_number < secret_number:
            print("You are too low.")

        elif guess_number > secret_number:
            print("You are too high.")
```

Comment: `game == False` evaluates to True or False — I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Typically, you would prompt for another game *after* exiting the inner loop, not while you are still inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operator `==` is used for assigning the value of game to False when the user chooses not to play again. **Previously, you were using the equality operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`**

For the sake of debug I just added a `print(f"Random number: {secret_number}")`

```
import random

game = True

while game:
    secret_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    status = True
    print(f"Random number: {secret_number}")
    while status:
        guess_number = int(input("Guess a number: "))

        if guess_number == secret_number:
            print("You won the game!!")
            status = False
            another_game = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n): ")

            if another_game.lower() == 'y':
                print("OK")
                break
            elif another_game.lower() == 'n':
                print("Thank you for playing!")
                game = False
                break

        elif guess_number < secret_number:
            print("You are too low.")
        elif guess_number > secret_number:
            print("You are too high.")
```